# Подстановка GET параметра в функцию JS

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите, а можно ли подставить GET параметр в функцию javascript?

```
$find.find("proekt[id=сюда вставить значение GET параметра]").each(function () {
```

Сам GET параметр получаю следующей функцией:

```
function parseUrlQuery() {
    var data = {}
        ,   pair = false
        ,   param = false;
    if(location.search) {
        pair = (location.search.substr(1)).split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < pair.length; i ++) {
            param = pair[i].split('=');
            data[param[0]] = param[1];
        }
    }
    return data;
}
var allParams = parseUrlQuery();
alert(allParams.id);
```

Comment: @Batyabest

    $find.find("proekt[id=" + allParams.id + "]").each(function () {})

Comment: Ха-ха!!! В кавычки надо было все запихнуть... а я и так, и сяк. Спасибо, добрый человек!!! Оформляй ответом, поставлю правильным.